# Use service in entity

Tags: php, symfony

I need to use a service in one of my entities but I don't know how to get the container. My attributes `$numHeure` and `$numSem` are conversions of `$dateDebut`.

```
<?php

namespace Agnez\CoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * EdtHeure
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="agnez_edt_heure")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Agnez\CoreBundle\Repository\EdtHeureRepository")
 */
class EdtHeure
{
    /**
    *@var datetime
    *@ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="dateDebut")
    */
    private $dateDebut;

    /**
    *@var int
    *@ORM\Column(type="int", name="numHeure")
    */
    private $numHeure;

    /**
    *@var int
    *@ORM\Column(type="int", name="numSem")
    */
    private $numSem;

    /**
     * Set dateDebut
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dateDebut
     *
     * @return EdtHeure
     */
    public function setDateDebut($dateDebut)
    {
        $this->dateDebut = $dateDebut;
        $servicedate = $this->container->get('agnez_core.servicedate');
        $this->numSem=$servicedate->numSem($date);
        $this->numHeure=$servicedate->numHeure($date);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I got the error:

> Notice: Undefined property:
>   Agnez\CoreBundle\Entity\EdtHeure::$container

Comment: On instantiating the model, you could add the container. Or better assign the service you need within the model to the model, this helps to keep the dependencies more visible

Comment: When have you go to set `numSem` and `numHeure` properties ? Everytime you change `dateDebut` ?

Comment: @Mcsky Yes, exactly.

Comment: @NicoHaase I assigned the service. Thanks. But this is not perfect to me because it's now impossible to setDateDebut anywhere else than in controller (like in another entity)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you need a service in your entity, and you should avoid it.

1) You can use a **doctrine Event** [[documentation]](http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html)

```
public function __construct(ServiceDate servicedate) 
{
    $this->servicedate = $servicedate
}

public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();

    if (!$entity instanceof EdtHeure) {
        return;
    }

    $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();

    // Call your service here
}
```

2) An other way is to **call the service outside your entity**

```
public function setDateDebut($dateDebut, $numSem, $numHeure)
```

And to call it outside, in a service EdtHeureUpdater. Its responsability will be to call various needed services and made change to your entity.

```
public function __construct(ServiceDate servicedate) 
{
    $this->servicedate = $servicedate
}

public function updateHeure(EdtHeure $edt, \DateTime $date)
{
    $numSem = $this->servicedate->numSem($date);
    $numHeure = $this->servicedate->numHeure($date)
    $edt->setDateDebut($dateDebut, $numSem, $numHeure)
}
```

Comment: Tanks for the help. I though about that but if i or anybody change dateDebut of EdtHeure, it should change numSem and numHeure too. That's why i wanted to link those in the entity.

If it's outside, i will always have to call the service updateHeure if i modifiy heureDebut right ?

Comment: @victoragn Yes. Added the doctrine events to my answer

Comment: According to your answer to my comment you should consider the doctrine event part of this answer :) Use service into entity isn't a good practice